# Float right an un-ordered list in a div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to float to right this menu list that will be dynamicaly loaded from a database, so I can't use a fixed height to the div containing the list as the list may may be longer than expected.

I have tried height="auto" for the containing div but it dont work once you float the list.

here is the code  http://jsbin.com/iyitom/1/edit

Comment: What do you want it to look like exactly?

Comment: I just want the list to float to the right.

Comment: have you tried the css attribute `overflow`?

Comment: Like this? http://jsbin.com/iyitom/6/edit

Comment: @MikeB well I never use that attribute yet,

Comment: @Explosion Pills I want it to the right not to the left (I made a mistake on my first comment, i edit it)

Comment: I'm no CSS pro, but I think `overflow` would be useful here. You would apply it to `.newscontent` I believe. Here is my attempt: http://jsbin.com/iyitom/7/edit

Comment: @MikeB well exacte but can it be completely to the right withought that small space just like Explosion Pills did?

Comment: I was messing up my directions.  I am a CSS pro and @MikeB's answer is the way to go.

Comment: @Explosion Pills OK, thank MikeB code is good at 99.9% :)

Comment: To get right up against the border like that, you have to remove the padding and margin. Like this: http://jsbin.com/iyitom/9/edit ??

Comment: @MikeB well now MikeB's code is good at 250% o_O ..... THANK A LOT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CSS attribute overflow](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/) is your friend here. You'll want to add `overflow: hidden;` to `.newscontent`

Comment: Woow, you know what? that Overflow stuff was going to be my next questions as I planed to use scrolling inside a div, you save my life.

Comment: But is it possible to customise the default scrolling bar with CSS? (it's for design stuff...)

Comment: this is from the same site as before: http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

Do a search for CSS customize scrollbar or something like that

Comment: Yeah sure, was doing it actually :)